# How to use @everywhere macro in a simple Julia code for parallel computing

Tags: julia

I am trying to write a simple Julia code for parallel computing.

I wrote a simple code based on this doc: https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/parallel-computing

```
@everywhere function test(x)
    return x * 2.0
end

nprocess = 5
addprocs(nprocess)
responses = Vector{Any}(nworkers())

for i in 1:nworkers()
    responses[i] = remotecall(test, i+1, i)
end

for res in responses
    wait(res)
end
```

However, I got this error message.

> ERROR: LoadError: On worker 2:
>
> UndefVarError: #test not defined

I think the @everywhere macro doesn't work correctly.

I'm using Julia 0.6.0.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

The `@everywhere` and the `addprocs` are in the reverse order (causing the added workers not to know about the function `test`). The other way around it works and doesn't do the `UndefVarError`:

```
nprocess = 5
addprocs(nprocess)
responses = Vector{Any}(nworkers())

@everywhere function test(x)
    return x * 2.0
end

for i in 1:nworkers()
    responses[i] = remotecall(test, i+1, i)
end

for res in responses
    wait(res)
end
```